# hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the all the subordinates when i select the supervisor. I am passing the employee_id from front end then it has to fetch the data who all are coming under him/her.

I have the tables structure for alignment and employee below.

tables :
Alignment :

```
ALIGNMENT_ID    NOT NULL    NUMBER(16)
TEAM_ID NOT NULL    NUMBER(16)
EMPLOYEE_ID     NUMBER(16)
ALIGNMENT_NAME  NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(200)
EXTERNAL_ID_1       VARCHAR2(200)
STATUS  NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(4)
STATUS_CHANGE_DATE  NOT NULL    DATE
MANAGER_ALIGNMENT_ID        NUMBER(16)
TEAM_ADMINISTRATOR      VARCHAR2(4)
REPORT_LEVEL        VARCHAR2(4)
ROLE        VARCHAR2(4)
POD_ALIGNMENT_ID        NUMBER(16)
```

employee :

```
EMPLOYEE_ID NOT NULL    NUMBER(16)
EXTERNAL_ID_1       VARCHAR2(200)
EXTERNAL_ID_2       VARCHAR2(200)
JOB_PROFILE_TYPE        VARCHAR2(4)
FIRST_NAME  NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(200)
MIDDLE_NAME     VARCHAR2(200)
LAST_NAME   NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(200)
SECOND_LAST_NAME        VARCHAR2(200)
DISPLAY_NAME        VARCHAR2(200)
BIRTH_DATE      DATE
STATUS  NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(4)
STATUS_CHANGE_DATE  NOT NULL    DATE
STATUS_REASON       VARCHAR2(4)
SAMPLING_STATUS     VARCHAR2(4)
MACHINE_NODE_ID     NUMBER(9)
LOGIN_ID        VARCHAR2(200)
TITLE       VARCHAR2(4)
```

data for alignment:

```
17432000000411  7888500000120271    17432000000427  india_ho    india_ho    ACTV    28-06-2013 06:44:53         0   VPOS
1006387676  7888500000120271    1006381821  EST REGION  EST REGION  ACTV    28-05-2013 15:41:56 17432000001417          RM
1006387677  7888500000120271    60000001963869  E-AREA1 E-AREA1 ACTV    28-05-2013 15:41:56 1006387676          DM
1006387678  7888500000120271    60000001963939  E-AREA2 E-AREA2 ACTV    28-05-2013 15:41:56 1006387676          DM
1006387679  7888500000120271    60000001963930  E-AREA3 E-AREA3 ACTV    28-05-2013 15:41:56 1006387676          DM
1006387680  7888500000120271    60000001963946  E-AREA4 E-AREA4 ACTV    28-05-2013 15:41:56 1006387676          DM
1006387681  7888500000120271    60000001963733  E-AREA6 E-AREA6 ACTV    28-05-2013 15:41:56 1006387676          DM
1006387682  1000000338771   60000001963734  E-AS-GUW-A07    E-AS-GUW-A07    ACTV    28-05-2013 16:17:30 1006387680          REP
1006387683  1000000338771   60000001963711  E-AS-GUW-A08    E-AS-GUW-A08    ACTV    28-05-2013 16:17:30 1006387680          REP
1006387684  1000000338772   60000001963729  E-AS-GUW-B07    E-AS-GUW-B07    ACTV    28-05-2013 16:17:30 1006387680          REP
1006387685  1000000338772   60000001963786  E-AS-GUW-B08    E-AS-GUW-B08    ACTV    28-05-2013 16:17:30 1006387680          REP
1006387686  1000000338771   18910000251233  E-CT-RAIP-A11   E-CT-RAIP-A11   ACTV    28-05-2013 16:17:30 1006387679          REP
1006387687  1000000338772   18910000194383  E-CT-RAIP-B11   E-CT-RAIP-B11   ACTV    28-05-2013 16:17:30 1006387679          REP
1006387688  1000000338771       E-MP-JABA-A09   E-MP-JABA-A09   INAC    19-01-2015 11:31:33 1006387681          REP
1006387689  1000000338773   60000001963891  E-MP-JABA-B09   E-MP-JABA-B09   ACTV    28-05-2013 16:17:30 1006034504          REP
1006387690  1000000338771   60000001963805  E-OR-BHUB-A05   E-OR-BHUB-A05   ACTV    28-05-2013 16:17:30 1006387678          REP
1006387691  1000000338772   60000001963873  E-OR-BHUB-B05   E-OR-BHUB-B05   ACTV    28-05-2013 16:17:30 1006387678          REP
```

In the alignment table we have the 
ROLE like 'VPOS'--1,'RM'--2,'DM'--3,'REP'--4.. I have given the order like top to bottom. VPOS is the head Person(Supervisor).

If I select the VPOS then all data has to fetch from the query. If I select the RM then DM and REP has to be displayed and if I select the DM then REP has to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the structure query, you can join it with employee query

```
select * from alignment
start with employee_id = %your_input_id%
connect by manager_alignment_id = prior alignment_id
```

Comment: if you join with another subquery, adjust the SELECT clause to `select rownum num, level lev, a.* from alignment a`, in `num` you'll get the order and in `lev` the hierarchy level (useful for traversing the tree), finally sort the joined query using `ORDER BY num`